# Почему не распознается синтаксис и символы?

Tags: intellij-idea, java, configuration

Вчера я что-то сделал, после чего `IntelliJ IDEA` перестал распознавать что либо.

И вот результат:
[image: Screen3]

Но в структуре проекта у меня все настроено вот скриншоты:
[image: screen1]
[image: screen2]

Все по умолчанию стоит, но ничего не поменялось. Искал почти везде но не нашел ответа.

Но что интересно все **компилируется, и работает**

[image: screen4]

Но эти "ошибки" в синтаксисе, режут глаз.

Как исправить это?

Comment: А кеш пробовали инвалидировать, file-invalidate cache/restart?

Comment: @a.chugunov как это сделать??

Comment: Выбрать file в меню и нажать invalidate caches)

Comment: @a.chugunov Спасибо большое) помогло :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема была решена в 1 простой шаг:

**`File --> Invalidate Chaches / restart`**

Там будет предупреждение того что локальная история сотрется

> The caches will be invalidated and rebuilt on the next startup.
>
> WARNING: Local History will be also cleared.
>
> Would you like to continue?

Соглашаемся и ждем пока IDEA перезагрузится, и снова настроиться, после чего все вернется в свои места.